# why in java multi-threading programmed is not getting the output i.e. lie between the 0 to 5050 and i'm always getting the output i.e 0?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
/*i'm always getting the o/p i.e 0 and not getting the other o/p like between 0<=x<=5050 like i saw 
in the durga software solutions*/

class ThreadChild extends Thread{     //child thread is starting from here
int totalsum=0;    
public void run() {    //calling the run() function
for(int i=1;i<=100;i++) {  //running the loop to calculate the sum of the first 100 number
totalsum=totalsum+1;
    }
}
}

/*i'm always getting the o/p i.e 0 and not getting the other o/p like between 0<=x<=5050 like i saw 
in the video of the youtube  durga software solutions*/

public class TotalSUmOfFirst100Numbers{ 
public static void main(String[] args) {
ThreadChild t=new ThreadChild();     //making the object f the child thread
t.start();//calling of the child thread
System.out.println(t.totalsum);
/*result is always printed i.e 0 not the other o/p like between 
0<=x<=5050*/
```

/*why in java multi-threading programmed is not getting the output i.e. lie between the 0 to 5050 and i'm always getting the output i.e 0 ?*/
}
}

Comment: Try to call t.join() after t.start(). The problem is that the main thread does not want till ThreadChild finishes execution.

Comment: but sir the problem is that without using  (these two function t.join() after t.start()) i can get the result bet 0<=x<=5050 right but i dont get it

Comment: You get totalsum=0 because it is the initial value (int totalsum=0). The main thread should wait till the secondary thread finished execution, otherwise you will always get zero.

Comment: Because you didn't give the thread enough time to execute, and your main thread is finished after print. Try put `Thread.sleep(1000);` before `System.out.println(t.totalsum);`

Comment: @PatrickChen that's not guaranteed to work. You need something like `join` to ensure the writes to `totalsum` *happen-before* the read in the main thread.

Comment: @AndyTurner, not guaranteed, just a suggestion so the OP can see the results and knows why. Should do this with `CompletedFuture` something.